# Why isn't "union all" doing what I expect?

Tags: sql, union

I created 2 summary tables form the same source data for different date ranges.
Now that I have these multiple summary tables, I want to put those tables together 
so that I will be able to run a summary on the combined table.

It's creating the summary table that is presenting the problem.

scratch.table_1 has   809,598 records.
scratch.table_2 has 1,228,176 records.

They both have the same set of fields from the source table, 
plus a "record_number" field I created on each table using count(1).

The code I used to put these two tables together was:

```
create table scratch.table_1_and_2
select * from scratch.table_1
union all
select * from scratch.table_2
```

I assumed that there would be 809,598 + 1,228,176 records in the new table (2,037,774 records).
But there are only 1,960,769 records in the new table.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: That seems unlikely. What happens if you create the table just from table_1 and then insert all from table_2?

Comment: It appears that this isn't the statement you used to create your table. This statement is missing the word `AS` after `table_1_and_2`, so it won't execute. Or perhaps that has something to do with your problem?

Comment: exists to the original tale and see what's missing. There certainly isn't enough info here to identify a solution. BTW what RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

One way to troubleshoot would be to identify some of the missing records and see what might be different about the data in those that would cause them to be left out. A `UNION ALL` should include duplicate records so duplicates shouldn't be the issue. Maybe there is some data issue that's causing those records to be dropped. Also I'm assuming there isn't any funny business with Views going on in the underlying tables and that no data loads are affecting your record counts.